# How to remotely track movement of android phone on map of a java desktop application using gps of android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps, geolocation

I developed an android application in which shows the current location of the user and updates the movement on google map API 2 in that application. My requirement is to remotely track and draw the path of this android device on java application on desktop/laptop.

usage: Cab driver uses the android application.
Cabs owner uses the desktop application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily archive that using the Google Maps Android API V2. Just send the current cab location LatLng values to your Java Application over a messaging & networking protocol. You can place the POST request in the setOnMyLocationChangeListener of the GoogleMap object.

```
map.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            double lat =  location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            //TODO: Send longitude and latitude to JAVA app
        }
    });
```